# Azure APIM - Version identifier in the Middle of url

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

By default when you version the Api in APIM, it puts the version identifier at the end of the suffix like this

/api/orchard/customer/v1

we'd like to have it in the middle like this

/api/orchard/v1/customer

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @pramodValavala-msft is right. Anyway, I tested this and came to the same question as you at first. I looked under "Settings - Version - Usage example" and there is it like you described `/api/orchard/customer/v1`, meaning that the version comes after the api. When I clicked on `Test - <an operation> - Request URL` it looks like here -> `/api/orchard/customer/v1/<operation>` which means `api/<version>/operation`. Could you provide the fully path you get extracted when testing?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually after the product URL suffix. The path is basically constructed like this

```
Product   - /api/orchard  
   +          +
Version   - /v1  
   +          +
Operation - /customer
```

If your back end requires it in a different way, you could always use the [`rewrite-uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL) policy

Comment: Problem here is that the suffix of each API has to be unique, we can separate out the customer part and make it part of the operation but we'll have several api's with the suffix /api/orchard and APIM doesn't allow for this repetition. Any work around for that?

Comment: Nope. They have to be unique. But wouldn't you just have multiple operations under one API instead?